# Get file path from chooser dropin

Tags: dropbox

I have implemented Dropbox chooser on my page. Now when the user selects a file, I want to get metadata about the chosen file. The metadata api requires `path` parameter, which is not present in the output from chooser. is there a way to get file path from the chooser output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately the Chooser doesn't currently offer the file metadata/path like this, but I'll be sure to pass this along as feedback.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an API to get metadata from links:

- Dropbox API V2: [/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata)
- Dropbox API V1: [/metadata/link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-link)

If the API is made with appropriate authentication, the path information is also included.

- Dropbox API V2: `path_lower`
- Dropbox API V1: `contents.path`

Source: [Re: How to get the file path from a preview link?](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-get-the-file-path-from-a-preview-link/m-p/28623/highlight/true#M831)